# how to substitute value in url from value in list and use FOR loop to loop thru them all

Tags: python, pandas, list, url

I am trying to figure out  how to replace "BATS" in the string in my code with the other exchanges in the list and loop thru them all to grab the stock data in one python script, rather than hard coding and creating multiple separate files.
Also, would like to use the same logic to replace the value of the resulting local .csv file (BATS_2021-01-19.csv) according to whatever exchange is being parsed. Here is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import os
import datetime


datetime = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
exchanges = ["BATS","US","SG","LSE","V","TSE"]

df = pd.read_csv('https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/eod-bulk-last-day/BATS?api_token=5f1343ba20.00275101&date=' + str(datetime))


Ticker = df['Code']
Date = df['Date']
Open = df['Open'].round(2)
High = df['High'].round(2)
Low = df['Low'].round(2)
Close = df['Adjusted_close'].round(2)
Volume = df['Volume']

total_df = pd.concat([Ticker, Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume],
                 axis=1, keys=['Ticker','Date','Open','High','Low','Close','Volume'])

filename = "BATS_"+(datetime)+".csv"

path = 'H:/EOD_DATA_RECENT/DOWNLOADS/'
full_path = os.path.join(path, filename)
total_df.to_csv(full_path, index=False)

print(total_df.head(5))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use use string formatting to specify the data in the url whilst looping over your exchanges.

Placing an `f` before your string quotations will allow to you input variables directly into the string by surrounding the variable name with `{}`

```
for ex in exchanges:
    print(f'https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/eod-bulk-last-day/{ex}?api_token=5f1343ba20.00275101&date={str(datetime)}')

    
https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/eod-bulk-last-day/BATS?api_token=5f1343ba20.00275101&date=2021-01-20
https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/eod-bulk-last-day/US?api_token=5f1343ba20.00275101&date=2021-01-20
https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/eod-bulk-last-day/SG?api_token=5f1343ba20.00275101&date=2021-01-20
https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/eod-bulk-last-day/LSE?api_token=5f1343ba20.00275101&date=2021-01-20
https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/eod-bulk-last-day/V?api_token=5f1343ba20.00275101&date=2021-01-20
https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/eod-bulk-last-day/TSE?api_token=5f1343ba20.00275101&date=2021-01-20
```

You should also rename your `datetime` variable, as you won't be able to use `datetime` again after declaring that variable.

```
datetime.datetime.now()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    datetime.datetime.now()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'datetime'
```

Comment: Thanks alot. can you think of a way I could also name the local file that I am writing to - to match the exchange that is being queried at that point in time?

Comment: You can use the each same feature. `filename = f"{ex}_{str(datetime)}.csv"`